# Why do both libstdc++ and libc++ not check for pointer and reference type D for the default unique_ptr constructor?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

The standard says:

> D shall satisfy the requirements of DefaultConstructible (Table 19), and that construction
>   shall not throw an exception.

for both of these constructors:

```
constexpr unique_ptr() noexcept;
explicit unique_ptr(pointer p) noexcept;
```

Yet both libc++ and libstdc++ only check `is_pointer<D>`. Why?

Comment: I would guess because the constructors attempt to default construct the object which would produce a compiler error if the object was not default constructible.

Comment: @DavidBrown: `D` is the type of the deleter here

Comment: @DavidBrown That does not explain why they don't follow the Standard and also reject a reference type `D`.

Comment: @AndyProwl Still, the constructor is going to default construct the deleter as well (and looking at the libstdc++ source, it does).

Comment: @rubenvb A reference would be rejected because attempting to default construct it would fail (which is not the case for a pointer, so the pointer check is necessary).

Comment: @DavidBrown: The one accepting a `pointer` perhaps, but not the default constructor (not in my version of stdlibc++ at least)

Comment: @AndyProwl Unless I am misreading, in [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01619_source.html#l00109) version, it default constructs a tuple containing the pointer and deleter which will default construct/value initialize the deleter (line 136).

Comment: @DavidBrown why don't you write that as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The constructors only needs to check if the type is a pointer because a function pointer is the only valid deleter type that could be value initialized and end up invalid.

These constructors both try to value initialize the deleter type (in `libstdc++` at least, but I'm guessig `libc++` is the same). This won't compile if `D` is a reference type or a function object type that does not satisfy `DefaultConstructible`. However it would compile if `D` was a function pointer, and you would end up with an invalid function pointer as the deleter, hence the pointer check being necessary.

It might be the case that the resulting error message would be clearer if they explicitly checked if they type is `DefaultConstructible`, but doing so is not strictly necessary.

Comment: +1. Makes sense to me, for some reason I missed the default-construction of the tuple when I first had a look

Answer (score 0):

That requirement is a constraint on the user, not on the implementation. If you try to use a deleter that does not have a default constructor the behavior is undefined. So you can plow through the implementation to try to figure out what your implementation does, or you can not do that. `<g>`.